# map with class value segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, memory, syntax

Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and set.

get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.
set(key, value) - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the least recently used item before inserting a new item.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev; 
};
class dlist{
    public:
        dlist(){}
        dlist(int capacity){
            cap=capacity;
        }
        void add(int value){
            node* n=new node;
            n->val=value;
            if (size==0){
                size++;
                tail=n;
                head=tail;
            }
            else {
                if (size==cap){
                    node* buf=head;
                    head=head->next;
                    head->prev=NULL;
                    delete buf;
                    size--;
                }
                tail->next=n;
                n->prev=tail;
                tail=n;
                size++;
            }
        }
        int getVal(){
            if (tail==NULL)
                return -1;
            return tail->val;
        }
    private:
        int cap;
        int size;
        node* tail;
        node* head;
};

class LRUCache{
    public:
        LRUCache(int capacity) {
            cap=capacity;
        }
        int get(int key) {
            if(cap!=0&&cache.find(key)!=cache.end())
                return cache[key].getVal();
            return -1;
        }
        void set(int key, int value) {
            if (cap==0)
                return;
            if(cache.find(key)==cache.end()){
                dlist d=dlist(cap);
                cache.insert(make_pair(key,d));
            }
            cache[key].add(value);
        }
    private:
        int cap;
        map<int,dlist> cache;
};

int main()
{
   LRUCache lru(3);
                   cout<<"asd";
   lru.set(1,9);
   lru.set(1,8);
   lru.set(1,1);
   lru.set(1,7);
   lru.set(2,9);
    cout<<lru.get(1)<<endl;
    cout<<lru.get(2)<<endl;
    cout<<lru.get(3)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

so I used a map and a custom double linked list, it seems to working fine with if I add the cout line right after initializing LRU, but it will have seg fault if I don't, I and not very sure what should I do to manage the memory use of LRU(if this is the problem)

Also if there's any line that could be better written(aside from std namespace) please tell me, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Please learn to format your code properly. It will make people _not_ want to gouge their eyes out with a rusty spoon

Comment: You're not supposed to store the most recent values every key has had, you're supposed to store the most recently used keys and their values. When the cache reaches its capacity, you should throw out the oldest (key, value) pair.

Comment: That is, `LRUCache lru(1); lru.set(1,9); lru.set(2,9); cout << lru.get(1);` should print `-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior since the member variables `size`, `tail`, and `head` of `dlist` are not initialized before being used.

Use

```
dlist() : dlist(0) {}
dlist(int capacity) : cap(capacity), size(0), tail(nullptr), head(nullptr) {}
```

That fixes the segmentation violation problem in my testing.

I recommend adding a constructor to `node` also:

```
struct node{

    node(int v) : val(v), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}

    int val;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev; 
};
```

and use

```
node* n=new node(value);
```

instead of

```
node* n=new node;
n->val=value;
```